# Expectation of continuous variable

Tags: expected-value, cumulative-distribution-functions

CDF of a random variable $X$ is given by table:

| $x < 1$ | $1 \leq x < 2$ | $ 2 \leq x < 3$ | $3 \leq x < 4 $ | $4 \leq x$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $0$ | $0.2$ | $0.35$ | $0.9$ | $1$ |

Find $E(X)$.

\begin{align*}
E(X)
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x) \,  dx \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{0} (x\cdot 0) \, dx
+ \int_{1}^{2} (x \cdot 0.2) \, dx
+ \int_{2}^{3} (x \cdot 0.35) \, dx 
+ \int_{3}^{4} (x \cdot 0.9) \, dx 
+ \int_{4}^{\infty} (x\cdot 1) \, dx \\
&= 0+0.3+0.875+3.15 \\
&=4.325
\end{align*}

Why is my answer not correct?

Comment: First off, the $f$ in your formula is the PDF of the variable, not the CDF. Second off, your variable $X$ appears to be discrete.

Comment: Does it mean that I should find pdf from cdf first and then apply pdf?

Comment: You should find the PMF (not PDF) because your random variable is discrete, not continuous. For example, $P(X=1)=0.2$. Then use the formula $E[X] = \sum_x x P(X=x)$.

Comment: How do I know that the variable is discrete here and not continious?

Comment: I thought something that looks like a range 1≤x<2 refers to continuous random variable?

Comment: It looks discrete because the CDF is not continuous

Comment: Look at the points where the CDF changes: these are exactly the values $X$ can take, and there are finitely many

Comment: If the CDF $F(x)$ increases in $x$ only by means of jumps, then the corresponding distribution is discrete with the PMF $$p(x)=\mathbf{P}(X=x)=\mathbf{P}(X\leq x)-\mathbf{P}(X<x)=F(x)-F(x^-),$$ where $F(x^-)=\lim_{a\to x^-}F(a)$ is the left-limit of $F$. On the other hand, if the CDF $F(x)$ increases continuously in $x$ and furthermore $f(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}F(x)$ exists with $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=1$, then the corresponding distribution is continuous with PDF $f$.

Comment: So, although CDF kind of encrypts the information on the distribution, you need to decrypt it in order to understand how the corresponding distribution actually looks like. CDF is just a convenient tool for encoding the distribution, but not necessarily the most intuitive or easy-to-work-with one. (That is why we often talk about PMF for discrete distributions and PDF for continuous distributions, which are easier to grasp intuitively and utilize.)

Answer (score 1):

You are given the CDF, not the pdf nor pmf.

The CDF functions jumps at certain values and remains constant otherwise. This is a behavior of a discrete random variable.

We can recover the probability as follows:

$$P(X=1)=P(1 \le X<2)-P(X<1)=0.2-0=0.2$$

Note that the probability doesn't increase over $1<X<2$, the random variable take those values with probability $0$.

After recovering the probability (pmf), you can compute the expected value by $$\sum_{i=1}^4 i P(X=i)$$

Alternatively, use $$E[X]=\int_0^\infty (1-F(X))\, dx$$

to compute the expected value.

Comment: (1*0.2)+(2*0.15)+(3*0.55)+(4*0.1)=2.55  Thank you.